# How to solve about this? I have a problem with template folder

Tags: django-templates

I am living problem about a project. I wanna create weather project but  I couldn't it yet. I don't know how to find html codes for template folder. Please help about this

Answer (score 0):

in settings.py has a place to register path to templates